# How to print values in flask terminal from post request with react?

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to print out the returned value of the data variable onto the terminal. I get the response as 200 However I want to print the actual value of the variable. It seems like I cannot use the print statement but only the return statement to be abe to view the data.

App.py with using the print statement:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form['username']
        print((jsonify(data))) 
    else:
        return ''
```

Error:

```
  TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
```

App.py with return statement:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form['username']
        print((jsonify(data))) 
    else:
        return ''
```

Output from terminal:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Jul/2020 19:02:24] "POST /api HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I want to be able to print something like '200,'Username is Jeff''.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it all - You are not returning anything

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form['username']
        print((jsonify(data))) 
    else:
        return ''
```

You only return if the request method is `GET`. What you need to do is to is to  return something when the request method is `POST`(Which is what you are receiving in the question). So you need to do something like this:

```
@app.route('/api', methods=['GET','POST'])
def api():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form['username']
        print((jsonify(data))) 
        return "Username is " + data
    else:
        return ''
```

assuming `data` is `Jeff`. The `print` statement only prints the data in your server console. You have to return something to whoever made the request.